# Auto Hot Key - keeping pressing the button causes the problem

Tags: autohotkey

I want to customize arrow key, making it vim-like.
(by assigning Ctrl+j to down-arrow and so on)

```
^h::Send {Left}
^j::Send {Down}
^k::Send {Up}
^l::Send {Right}
```

The problem is that when I keep pressing the key, say "ctrl+j" to go down in any text editor,
somewhat the character "j" will appear in 10+seconds.
How can it happen and how to avoid it?jjjjjj

thank you in advance.

Comment: Works fine here. Is that all the code in your script? Try it first in a script with no other code and close all other scripts. And install the latest AHK version.

Comment: using v2 solved the problem! Now it's working as i wish. Thank you for the advice of versin update.